# Ubuntu offline shared folder

Tags: ubuntu, storage, nfs, iscsi

So I've got a PABX (Ubuntu) that records calls to /opt/recordings. Because this folder can get very large I don't want to keep it on my fast storage so I moved it over to our slow iSCSI storage. So /opt/recordings is a iSCSI volume stored on a remote iSCSI target (Windows Server 2016).

I'm worried that if the slow storage box goes offline while the PABX is online, that the recordings being made at that point will go missing.

Is there a type of storage abstraction layer that I can use that will keep writing to the /opt/recordings folder and write the data back to the iSCSI volume as soon as the iSCSI target comes back online? iSCSI isn't a must- I'm open to all options.